# Cannot re-add the data if deleted from sql server

Tags: powerapps

I'm new to PowerApps and what I'm trying to do is to create a form that will add data to my SQL server table. It all works fine to the moment I personally delete the data from SQL server and try to add it again.

The error appears when I try to add the data I removed from SQL server once again. It says "The element was already created on the server", but on SQL server it does not exists cause I deleted it with a query.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are probably experiencing is some sort of caching from the data source in the app; the app will load some of the data from the SQL table, and it knows what is the primary key for that. If you try to add a new record with that same primary key, the app will complain saying that it cannot do that (which would be a primary key constraint violation).

What you can do is to refresh the data source (`Refresh('[dbo].[your_table_name]')`), so that the cache will be updated with the latest data from the server. The screen capture below shows a scenario that is likely the same as the one you have - if I remove a row from the server side, but the app doesn't know about it, it fails to insert it again with the same primary key; once I refresh the data source, it works.

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: @thanks it solved my case. Also I've found it easier to use collection instead of using direct data idk why.